# Configuring rsyslog output format strings

Tags: syslog

I'm setting up rsyslog for an application and using the following configuration:

```
$FileCreateMode 0644
if $programname == 'proxy' then /var/log/proxy/log
& stop
```

This generates log entries like the following:

```
Feb 26 20:45:46 ip-10-161-71-236 proxy[2562]: Feb 26, 2022 8:45:46 PM org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool$1 lambda$run$0
```

This stuff is being shipped over to CloudWatch by CloudWatch Agent, so the part `ip-10-161-71-236 proxy[2562]` in the log line is not needed. How can I define a format string for the log entry that leaves this out?

Comment: [RSyslog Documentation - rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html)

Comment: I wouldn't change the string format, as it makes maintenance harder (especially for people who aren't you). The message format is [RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424), which is the standard syslog format. IMO doing some sort of pre- (or post-) processing would be a cleaner solution.